# How enable ComboBox in WinForms to save text from keyboard?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selectedvalue

I have a ComboBox with a datasource from a DataTable (DataView). For example, this source return 5 items in my ComboBox.

If I don't want to choose one of these 5 items, and I need to add another new to save it in my database, how I can do it?

my combobox values :

```
bankAccountCombo.DisplayMember = "Account";
bankAccountCombo.ValueMember = "Account";
bankAccountCombo.DataSource = bankAccountView;
bankAccountCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

ComboBox.SelectedValue is saved in database by this line :

```
this.bankAccountCombo.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", contractsBindingSource, "InvoicingIBAN", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

my problem is at `ComboBox.SelectedValue` ..... how I can Select another value outside the returned list from DT??

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to bind both `SelectedValue` and `Text` to `contractsBindingSource.InvoicingIBAN`.

```
bankAccountCombo.DataBindings.Add("Text", contractsDataSource, "InvoicingIBAN", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
bankAccountCombo.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", contractsDataSource, "InvoicingIBAN", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Ensure that your ComboBox allows user input by setting `bankAccountCombo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;`

Comment: aha, thanks. Is not needed to  put both binds, only "Text". I see this can save a free text or the selectedvalue from combo, if exist.